# Google chrome, native client support and development

Tags: c++, browser, google-chrome, google-nativeclient

I would like to write a small C++ app and run it on chrome using the native client API.

I have a few questions though:
1) I compiled the examples on Ubuntu and ran the code on firefox but can't run it on chrome (using version 5.0.342.7 beta)
Do I need to install something? An extension/plugin?

2) I can't find a single online application I could run? Links anyone, I want to see the power of this thing without having to compile the code locally.

Thanks for your help,

-hbt

PS:
I don't know what's the policy with asking multiple questions. If it's a problem, let me know and I will create multiple threads.

---

More details:
Already read doc at 
http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/wiki/NativeClientInGoogleChrome

Running with --enable-nac from the command line and I have this error

.mozilla/plugins/sel_ldr_bin.trace: cannot dynamically load executable

I already built and installed sel_ldr
./scons -c --mode=opt-linux sel_ldr
./scons -c --mode=nacl
./scons run_all_tests
./scons --mode=opt-linux npGoogleNaClPlugin
./scons --verbose firefox_install

Works in firefox! not in chrome

Double checked about:plugins in chrome
Native Client Plugin is enabled and pointing to 
.mozilla/plugins/libnpGoogleNaClPlugin.so

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running it using Chromium?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm using google-chrome not the custom chromium package.

Comment: I tried running chrome dev (v11) with NativeClient enabled on Ubuntu 10.10 with no luck. I have not dug deep yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you launch Chromium with the following parameter --enable-nac.

Answer (score 0):

1) Firefox is not supported now(maybe in the future it will be supported again). It seems that you are not using the latest SDK.

2) You need to use newer Chrome browser(yes Chrome is running nativeclient module now as well). In Ubuntu, you may use the google repository for testing

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/ stable non-free main

deb http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/ testing non-free main
```

and the package of the chrome in dev channel is named 'google-chrome-unstable'. For more information of google linux repository, refer to: www.google.com/linuxrepositories/

3) Native Client's SDK is separated into nativeclient-sdk. It's easy to use. Here is the guide: http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient-sdk/wiki/HowTo_GetStarted

Have Fun!